# Dynamically change data-iconpos in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making a jQuery Mobile app. I would like to be able to set attribute of navbars in function in another file. It means, I want to change navbar's atrributes which are in many html files, by one function in .js file.

I tried to change class in page create but it didnt worked for me:

```
$('div[data-role$="navbar"]').bind('pagecreate', function(){
    div=this;
    alert(div.class);
    div.setAttribute("class","ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a");
}
```

Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8ES65/) is an example for you and this is a code:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
    $('div[data-role$="navbar"] ul li a span span').addClass('new-class');
});
```

This line will execute for every page:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
```

And this line will fore example change color of navbar text:

```
$('div[data-role$="navbar"] ul li a span span').addClass('new-class');
```

This part od code can be found at the bottom of my jsFiddle example (HTML part)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery why don't you make it easier on yourself and use it inside you handler?

```
$('div[data-role$="navbar"]').bind('pagecreate', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  alert( $this.attr('class') );
  $this.attr('class','ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a');

  //Possibly you mean ...
  //$this.addClass('ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a');
}
```